# Python module import globally

Tags: python, module

My question seems very simple but I can’t find an answer. 
I created a project with this structure :

- My project       : **main.py**
- My project/src : **data.py**

In the main program I import pandas and also data.py.

In **data.py** I also use pandas but I have an error message because the module pandas is not found. I need to integrate in **data.py** : `import pandas as pd` to use it.

So my question is simple : how can I make just one call to pandas (in **main.py**) to have access to it in all of my project?

Comment: You cannot. Every module that uses `numpy` has to import *something* to add an appropriate name to its global namespace.

Comment: Er, `pandas`, not `numpy`.

Comment: Please provide the bits of code you're executing in your files.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't possible but what you can do is the following:

Inside **src/data.py**, have whatever data you want to use with pandas, for example:

```py
data = {'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[5,6,7,8]}
```

and then in your **main.py**:

```py
import pandas as pd
from src.data import *

print(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

which produces the following output:

```
   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7
3  4  8
```

---

### EDIT:

If you really do not want to import pandas again in **data.py** but absolutely must use it's functionality in that file, you could do the following:

**main.py:**

```py
import pandas as pd
from src.data import *

dl = DataLoader(pd, 'src/dict.json')
print(dl.get_data())
```

**src/data.py:**

```py
class DataLoader:
  def __init__(self, pd, _file):
    self.file = _file
    self.pd   = pd

  def get_data(self):
    return self.pd.read_json(self.file)
```

**src/dict.json:**

```
{"A":[1,2,3], "B":[4,5,6], "C":[7,8,9]}
```

here you are passing `pandas` to the class `DataLoader` in your **data.py** file and thus are using its functionality in the **data.py** file without importing it in that file as requested.

For completeness, the code I suggest produces the following output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

Comment: So I need to call pandas twice ?

Comment: It means that I have pandas twice in memory ? Or python manages this automatically ?

Comment: Pandas is only ever called once in my suggestions. src/data.py contains ONLY `data = {'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[5,6,7,8]}` with no other lines of code.

Comment: I cannot do what you propose as a solution. 
In main.py I have to call pandas and it’s the same in data.py. 
So I need to call twice pandas, in main and data

Comment: Please provide an example of where you have to call pandas in data.py

Comment: In data.py something like this : def data(): pd.read(...) return(df)

Comment: It is sthing like that.

Comment: @Jacques thanks for clarifying. I've updated my answer in response

Comment: Last question : is it really a problem to import twice pandas ? Does it create memory problem or sthing else ? 
From my point of view it is simpler to import it twice.

Comment: @Jacques there's nothing wrong with importing it twice but my answer addresses your desire to not do that.